# Getting nil when setting annotation. value to mapitems, mapkit swift 4

Tags: swift, mapkit

I'm creating an app in swift 4 using Xcode 9 and mapkit. Right now, I want the user to click on certain buttons and then annotations pop up on the map corresponding to the button clicked. Example: the "Restaurant" button is clicked so annotations pop up at all restaurants in a given area.

The problem occurs when adding the annotation to my mapview. I get a fatal error: found nil while unwrapping. Here is the code:

```
enum annotations : String {
    case restaurants = "Restaurants"
    case movieTheater = "Movie Theater"
    case shopping = "Shopping"
    case bowling = "Bowling"
    case park = "Park"
    }

    //In viewcontroller.swift
    var annotationPoints : [MKMapItem] = []

    @IBAction func annotationClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
        guard let title = sender.currentTitle, let annotation =       annotations(rawValue: title) else {
            return
        }
        //only added two cases to test
        switch annotation {
        case .restaurants:
            getAnnotations(query: annotation.rawValue)
        default:
            getAnnotations(query: annotation.rawValue)
        }
    }

    func getAnnotations(query : String) {
        print("creating request")
        
        let request  = MKLocalSearchRequest()
        print("setting request")
        request.naturalLanguageQuery = query
        
        let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.5, longitudeDelta: 0.5)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: (mapView.userLocation.location?.coordinate)!, span: span)
        print("setting region")
        request.region = region
        print("creating search")
        let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)
        print("starting search")
        search.start { (response, error) in
            guard let response = response else {
                return
            }
            self.annotationPoints = response.mapItems
            var annotation : GetAnnotationPins?
            
            print(self.annotationPoints)
            for points in self.annotationPoints {
                print("the points name is \(String(describing: points.name))")
                print("the points number  is \(String(describing: points.phoneNumber))")
                print("the points coordinates are \(points.placemark.coordinate)")
                
                annotation?.title = points.name
                print("the title is \(String(describing: annotation?.title))")
                
                annotation?.subtitle = points.phoneNumber
                print("the subtitle is \(String(describing: annotation?.subtitle))")
                
                annotation?.coordinate = points.placemark.coordinate
                print("the coordinates are \(String(describing: annotation?.coordinate))")
                
                print("the annotaiton is \(String(describing: annotation))")


                self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation!)
                
            }
        }
    }


    //separate class for pin annotation 

    class GetAnnotationPins : NSObject, MKAnnotation {
        var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
        var subtitle: String?
        var title: String?
        
        init(coordinate : CLLocationCoordinate2D, subtitle : String, title : String) {
            self.coordinate = coordinate
            self.subtitle = subtitle
            self.title = title
        }
    }

}
```

Console print out:

```
the points name is Optional("Lin\'s Garden") // restaurant near my location 
the points number  is Optional("‭+1 (715) 693-8899‬")
the points coordinates are CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude:        44.791603000000002, longitude: -89.700630000000004)
the title is nil
the subtitle is nil
the coordinates are nil
the annotaiton is nil
```

Comment: You declare a local variable `annotation` in your `getAnnotations(query:)`, but I cannot find any code setting a value to the variable.

Comment: You can already see that your values are not `Strings` but `Optionals<String>`. You have to unwrap them (if you are certain that they are not `nil` just put a `!` behind it

Comment: Something like `annotation?.title = points.name!` should do the trick if I am right

Comment: Still getting nil on title and subtitle when adding "!" to the end of .name and .phoneNumber. Can't add a "!" to placemark.coordinates since it isn't an optional

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should initialize `GetAnnotationPins` class. Try the following code:

```
for points in self.annotationPoints {
    var annotation = GetAnnotationPins(coordinate: points.placemark.coordinate,
        subtitle: points.phoneNumber,
        title: points.name)
    ....
}
```

And replace

```
 self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation!)
```

with

```
 self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
```

Comment: Thanks it worked but i wasn't able to use optional binding since GetAnnotationPoints isn't an optional type.

Comment: one other quick question, how would i go about making sure that phone number isn't nil (or any other value when initilizing annotation) and still adding the annotation with the info that isn't nil. So if i search something and number is nil but it still adds the annotation with just the name and coordinates.

Comment: You can use `??` eg. `subtitle = points.phoneNumber ?? "no message"`

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks a ton!

Comment: Your welcome. Please accept my answer if I helped you :)